# MYSQL list users that only specific type of app

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
Username    Published App
1stLineS     Citrix Delivery Services Console
1stLineS     Mencap@Work2-1
1stLineS     PB Service Desktop
1stlineWB    PB Service Desktop
aabidam  Business Object Full Client
aabidam  Epicor
aabidam  Mencap Desktop with Acrobat
aabidam  Powerplan
aabidam  Therefore Navigator
aabidam  Thin Client Desktop
aarong   Mencap @ Work Desktop
AarthiT  Mencap@Work2-1
AbbeyY   Mencap@Work2-1
abbiemc  Mencap@Work2-1
abbyf    Mencap@Work2-1
abbygailf    Mencap@Work2-1
Abbyh    GLH Contractors Web Portal
abdio    
abdio    PB Service Desktop
abdio    RDP NC-BACKUP01
abdouD   Mencap@Work2-1
abdulm   Mencap@Work2-1
AbigailE     Mencap@Work2-1
AbigailJ     Mencap Desktop with Acrobat
AbigailJ     Mencap@Work2-1
abim     Mencap@Work2-1
abiodunb     Mencap@Work2-1
abiodunb     Powerplan
adamd    ActiveH
adamd    Mencap@Work2-1
AdamHal  Mencap@Work2-1
```

I need to get back a list of users that only use certain type of "published apps" desktops...

I've managed to filter them previously for other queries as strings cotaining the following values

```
"%Mencap@Work2-1%"
"%@%"
"%Desktop%"
"%RDP%"
```

I need to get back the following list

```
Username
1stlineWB
aarong
AarthiT
AbbeyY
abbiemc
abbyf
abbygailf
abdio
abdouD
abdulm
AbigailE
AbigailJ
abim
AdamHal
```

i;ve tried with a querye like this

```
$sql = "SELECT username, publishedapp, count(*) as cnt
from (select username, min(publishedapp) as publishedapp
      from tbl_name t
      group by username
      having count(DISTINCT publishedapp LIKE \"%desktop%\" AND  publishedapp LIKE \"%@%\" AND  publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\") = 1
    ) cnt
group by publishedapp
order by count(*) desc
";
```

but this returns users that user that not contain "desktop" exclusively...

Comment: If you only want users returned, why does your list have multiple users?

Comment: your right, good point. let me edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want something like this:
If you want users who only have the set of "published" apps in your list, then:

```
select username, group_concat(publishedapp) as apps, count(*) as cnt
from tbl_name t
group by username
having sum(publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%desktop%\" AND
           publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%@%\" AND 
           publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\") = 0
order by cnt desc;
```

This returns users who only have those apps.  It also gives the list of apps in the second column and the count in the third.

Comment: Your a life saver one more time... one thing tho, how could I count for the individual set of apps? excluding duplicates? ive tried DISTINCT like thi:
SELECT DISTINCT and count(DISTINCT *) neither happened to work...

Answer (score 0):

Should that be a `OR` condition instead like

```
having SUM (CASE WHEN publishedapp LIKE '%desktop%' 
                  OR  publishedapp LIKE '%@%' 
                  OR  publishedapp LIKE '%RDP%' THEN 1 ELSE 0) = 1
```

Comment: ive tried this
`SELECT username, publishedapp, count(*) as cnt
from (select username, min(publishedapp) as publishedapp
      from tbl_name t
      group by username
      having SUM (CASE WHEN publishedapp LIKE "%desktop%"
                  OR  publishedapp LIKE "%@%"
                  OR  publishedapp LIKE "%RDP%" THEN 1 ELSE 0) = 1
    ) cnt
group by publishedapp
order by count(*) desc` doesnt even return a result...
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\New\test4.php on line 70`